# Kibana 5.1 shared short url's do not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana, amazon-elasticsearch

I am running elasticsearch 5.1 using the AWS elasticsearch service.  By default the kibana plugin is available with an AWS ES installation.

Using the kibana 'share' function I then select the 'short URL'.   When people go to the short URL they get this error.

> No handler found for uri [/_plugin/kibana/goto/61256d5aa70d506c1b7f2ec63c5a64c1] and method [GET]

I'm curious if anyone has any ideas on how to address this.   We are not traversing any proxies when hitting the kibana interface.   This was tested going straight to the kibana endpoint from a browser on an unrestricted ES domain.

Here is an screen shot of me creating the short url
[image]

Here is a screen shot of me visiting the short url in another browser tab
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: same issue with AWS ES 6.3 - I am running a nginx reverse proxy infront though